# I'm trying to use jquery to create a div containing columns but I can't get my array to format correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that contains dates. and for some reason I can't get it to show on my screen I've been debugging for a few days now and I've tracked it down to a single line, but the line has worked before and I can't figure out what the issue might be.

The array looks like this:

```
  var selectItems = 
[ "05-26-2017", "06-02-2017", "06-09-2017", 
"06-16-2017", "06-23-2017", "06-30-2017", "07-07-2017", "07-14-2017",     
"07-21-2017", "07-28-2017"...];
```

It's passed as an argument from another function, but that's how it's showing in console.log().

I might be going about this the wrong way, maybe even a lot further around then I need to but this is what I've come up with:

```
 1.    function setTHead(selectItems) {
    2        var formatString;
    3.        for (var x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
    4.            formatString = selectItems[x].replace(/[^0-9/-]/g,     "").toString();
    5.           console.log(selectItems);
    6.          $('#datTab').append("<div id='col" + x + "' class='column'>'" + formatString + "'</div>");
    7.       }
    8.    }
```

the array up top is what's showing from the console.log 5 lines down.
the sixth line is what is seeming to give me issues.  Nothing is put on the page at all.
I'm getting a console error saying:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: selectItems is undefined setTHead@http://localhost/mySite/script.js:136:9
startUp2@http://localhost/mySite/script.js:146:5
@http://localhost/mySite/table.php:19:9
mightThrow@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3586:52
resolve/</process<@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3654:49
setTimeout handler*resolve/<@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3692:37
fire@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3320:30
fireWith@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3450:29
fire@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3458:21
fire@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3320:30
fireWith@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3450:29
ready@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3923:13
completed@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3933:9
EventListener.handleEvent*@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:3949:9
@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:39:9
@http://localhost/mySite/lib/jquery.js:17:3
 undefined
```

followed by:

```
TypeError: selectItems is undefined
```

and thats pointing to line 6.

if anyone has any advice I would be very much appreciative.  Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** A little more code:

```
function startTblView(defSel) {

    if (defSel === true) {
        setCookie('defSel', true, 7);
    } else{
        setCookie('defSel', false, 7);
    }
    saveSelected();

    window.open('table.php', '_self');

    defSel = getCookie('defSel');


if (defSel) {

    selectItems = getDefDates();
}else {

    selectItems = reGetSelected();
}
 setTHead(selectItems);
}
```

defSel, is a boolean passed from my last page stating whether I'm doing a default view or a custom view, the custom view is passed from saveSelected();

saveSelected is a function for just saving the selected global value as a cookie so I can pull it out on the next page.

getDefDates pulls the default values for the array

reGetSelected, gets the selected array from the cookie.

I apologize for wonky naming conventions. I'm the only one working on this site and I'm just making sure the names don't overlap.

Comment: `jQuery.Deferred` ? I suspect an async mechanism, and you may be trying to iterate over your array before the async call has finished fetching it. Can you show a bit more of your code? How do you fetch this array? How and where do you call the setTHead function?

Comment: the array is pulled from another page, I send it to a cookie, then I fetch it after the next page is loaded. I've had to go around the world to get it formatted and unformatted correctly, but I can't use AJAX, so I'm trying to find a way to work around it.

Comment: yeah, ajax or not, the problem is asynchronism anyway. You're trying to work on selectItems before it's finished fetching, so it's undefined. But so far, we have no idea how the array is fetched, with what function, after what process etc. That's why I asked for more code :)

Comment: @Jeanze where you get the array? backend? or client side

Comment: it's all local from another web page, trying to get it parsed into JSON and using PHP to pass it to the other page was giving me all kinds of issues.

Comment: So would it be better to try setting a wait on it? to give it time to catch up?

Comment: @JeremyThille I added the main function that calls setTHead. I may be trying to do too much at once. This is the first project of this scale I've attempted by myself. So, forgive me if I made a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

HTML code

```
<div id="datTab"></div>
```

JS code

```
 var selectItems = 
[ "05-26-2017", "06-02-2017", "06-09-2017", 
"06-16-2017", "06-23-2017", "06-30-2017", "07-07-2017", "07-14-2017",     
"07-21-2017", "07-28-2017"];

function setTHead(selectItems) {
  var formatString;
  $.each( selectItems, function( index, value ){
    formatString = value.replace(/[^0-9/-]/g,     "").toString();
    $('#datTab').append("<div id='col" + index + "' class='column'>'" + value + "'</div>");
    });
};
```

You can use $.each, its better than 'for' with javascript.

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword this refers to the element.

I did a JsFiddle

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ohbfoxd5/4/).

Comment: I tried adding that into my code.  Everything looked like it was working correctly, but it still didn't append anything to #datTab.

Comment: that's the only #datTab I have in my entire site, and so far that 's the only time I mention it in my code.

Comment: Its works in this JsFiddle. So, maybe this function is called many times, and in the last time, with a array empty ?

Comment: I threw console.log(formatString); right after the formatString line, and I changed value to formatString in the next line and still I'm not getting anything.  the jquery.deferred exception is gone, but it's still not showing up through.

Comment: @Greg `You can use $.each, its better than 'for' with javascript` On what base?? Why is it "better"? `for` is vanilla JS so it's necessarily faster than `$.each`.